# Docker create ipv6 network fail

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kind

I want to use kind to create one k8s cluster. but it report that docker network create fail. I check that docker network is just have 4(`docker network ls | wc -l`).
I don't know why, do anybody know that? Hope to get your suggestion.

```
./kind create cluster

ERROR: failed to create cluster: failed to ensure docker network: command "docker network create -d=bridge -o com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=true --ipv6 --subnet fc00:f853:ccd:e793::/64 kind" failed with error: exit status 1
Command Output: Error response from daemon: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried running `docker network create -d=bridge -o com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=true --ipv6 --subnet fc00:f853:ccd:e793::/64 kind` first, then creating and running container again?

Comment: sure. I have done that. 
but I got the error msg.`Error response from daemon: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network`

Comment: I had also try `docker network create -d=bridge --subnet=172.0.0.1/24 hello` and this command successfully to execute.
But I try another command `docker network create -d=bridge world` would fail with the error msg `Error response from daemon: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network`

Comment: Please edit the question to include the contents of your `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and output of `docker info`

Comment: The /etc/docker/daemon.json is not exist.
Thanks. I think may be my machine may be limited by IT. 
because the machine is company machine, some information is not good to show.

Comment: I think this problem may be caused by some network strategy that are config by the IT office. I have switch to another personal machine. and the problem did not occur.

Answer (score 0):

**Enable IPV6 on Kind Cluster:**

1. Create a `daemon.json` file on your local machine, if already exists, add the following settings too:

```sh
$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8:1::/64"
}
```

2. Reload settings for docker:

```sh
$ sudo systemctl reload docker
```

3. Create Kind configuration file as following:

```sh
$ cat ~/kind-config.yaml 
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
networking:
  ipFamily: ipv6
```

4. Create your kind cluster with the given configuration:

```sh
$ kind create cluster --config=$HOME/kind-config.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. I have try it. But It's not effect. I have swtiched to another machine and the problem is disappeared.